# Excel VBA: Color range based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing code so that when the value of a cell has a certain value it highlights a range for that row (columns G-O, but not the entire row). The code below is recognizing the values of "c" correctly but coloring random rows. For example, when row 2 (O2) has a value under 40, it colors row 4. Please help!

```
Sub color()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim c As Variant

    lastrow = Range("o" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In Range("O1:O" & lastrow)
        If c.Value < 40 Then
             ' MsgBox (c)
             Range(Cells(c, 7), Cells(c, 15)).Interior.ColorIndex = 7 
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Conditional Formatting will do this without the need of VBA.  Is there a reason you want to do this in VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See changes below. It has to do with how you are using `Cells()`. The way you have it, it will use the value of "c", not the row.

```
Sub color()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim c As Variant
lastrow = Range("o" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In Range("O1:O" & lastrow)
        If c.Value < 40 Then
            ' MsgBox (c)
             Range(Cells(c.Row, 7), Cells(c.Row, 15)).Interior.ColorIndex = 7 
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```